# Convert pfx to pem

Tags: ssl, openssl

I know there are many commands (openssl) to export pfx to pem BUT I need one thing different: I need to export the public key to a pem file and the private key to another file. Most of the commands and sites (some sites convert the pfx format to anyone I need) will only generate a single *.pem file.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta: this isn't a programming or development question, and will likely be closed as offtopic.

If you want the privatekey and the *certificate* (which *contains* the publickey but is not the publickey as such), this is a dupe of several questions in other Stacks where it is ontopic, including at least:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-export-my-private-key-from-a-java-keytool-keystore/
https://serverfault.com/questions/715827/how-to-generate-key-and-crt-file-from-jks-file-for-httpd-apache-server
https://serverfault.com/questions/806141/is-the-alert-ssl3-read-bytessslv3-alert-bad-certificate-indicating-that-the-s (disclosure: my answer)

Alternatively since PEM files are structured text, you can parse the output of a single `pkcs12` command by any number of text-handling programs such as awk:

```
 openssl pkcs12 <p12 | awk '/-BEGIN ENC/,-END ENC/{print >"privkey"} \
   /-BEGIN CERT/,/-END CERT/{if(!n)print >"cert"} /-END CERT/{n++}'
 # for unencrypted privatekey add -nodes and select BEGIN/END PRIV
```

---

If you truly want the publickey, you can create it in algorithm-generic X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo form, from either the privatekey or the certificate:

```
 # from the certificate
 openssl x509 <certfile -noout -pubkey >pubkey
 openssl pkcs12 <p12file -nokeys -clcerts | openssl x509 -noout -pubkey >pubkey

 # from the privatekey
 openssl pkey <privkey -pubout >pubkey
 openssl pkcs12 <p12file -nocerts -nodes | openssl pkey -pubout >pubkey
```

This format is used by some OpenSSL functions (which calls it PUBKEY to distinguish from the several algorithm-specific PublicKey's), and low-level Java (which calls it `X509EncodedKeySpec`), and pretty much nothing else. Note systems using the bare public key are often insecure; that's exactly why most systems embed the publickey in a certificate.

If the key is RSA and you want the algorithm-specific (PKCS1 RSAPublicKey) format, in OpenSSL 1.1.0 (and presumably up) then use:

```
 # from the SPKI publickey as above
 openssl rsa <RSApub_spki [-inform DER] -pubin -RSAPublicKey_out [-outform DER] >RSApub_pkcs1 
 # from the privatekey 
 openssl rsa <RSAprivate [-inform DER] -RSAPublicKey_out [-outform DER] >RSApub_pkcs1
```

This is used rarely by a few OpenSSL functions and AFAIK nothing else; see caveat above.

Comment: Thanks my friend! Your were very clear! I just didnt understand one thing: when I export my pfx file to pem it exports the private key and the certificate. How do I get the public key from the certificate?

Comment: What format of public key? There are two PEM formats for each algorithm supported by OpenSSL; I already showed the cases handled by commandline, and writing code or workarounds for the several remaining cases would take a lot of time most of which would be wasted because you keep asking ambiguous questions.

Comment: My friend, I got the privatekey/certificate exported using this command "pkcs12 -in file.pfx -out output_file.pem -nodes". The problem is that even after reading all you said it does not say how to export the public key from that!

Comment: Please read the paragraph beginning "If you truly want the publickey, you can create it in [SPKI] ..." and the paragraph beginning "If the key is RSA and you want [PKCS1] ...". Those are the two options that work from commandline. If you don't want one of those two options, specify which format out of the roughly 6 PEM publickey formats you want.